# How to get the values from dynamically created HTML controls in .vb code behind

Tags: html, vb.net

I am dynamically creating HTML controls on Page load.

My code looks like following:

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder
Dim i as Integer = 0
sb.Append("<table">)
For Each item as myClass IN myList
    i += 1
    sb.Append("<tr><td>")
    sb.Append("<div id=mydiv"& i &">"+tem.myValue+"</div><br>")
    sb.Append("<textarea id = txt"&i&" name =txt></textarea></td>")
    sb.Append("<td><select id = validate"&i&"><option value =''>Choose one</option><option value ='Yes'>Yes</option><option value ='No'>No</option></select></td>)
      ----------
      ---------
     sb.Append("</table>")
     myDiv.InnerHtml = sb.Tostring
```

Explaination of above code:

I am creating multiple `<textarea>` textbox and `<select>` dropdown in the for each loop and assigning the complete string to my div(myDiv.InnerHtml = sb.Tostring).

So it will create multiple textboxes and dropdown with id dynamically genereated using i

```
<div id=mydiv"& i&......
```

Now I want to access the values in the above textboxes and dropdowns in another button click event.

**I am creating dynamic controls in PageLoad event**

Is this doable? Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always access these by looking at Request.Form("txt" & i) or Request.QueryString if you send it as get.

But this isn't very asp.netY. If you create [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) controls, you could access the .Text property to get the value.